# Setting Up An Array Method

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I need to set up a method that is constructed like this

```
+addBook(aBook:book): boolean
```

I know that `+` means it's `public` and it needs to be a `boolean` with the name `addBook` but I'm not sure how to set up the `aBook:book` part.

I know that it wants me to set up an array as a parameter to the method but I don't know exactly how to set it up. Would it be something like this?

```
 public boolean addBook(aBook[] book)
```

Comment: It could just be me, but I read it as wanting a method (called `addBook`) to take a `aBook` and call it `book`, something like `public boolean addBook(aBook book)`. As to your "actual" question, I'd recommend just writing some code and seeing what happen

Comment: @MadProgrammer Isn't the type on the right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i agree with you, it doesn't make sense to have a method called addBook and then you pass in an array of books.

Comment: @shmosel Given how the method return type is laid out, you're probably right

Comment: @MadProgrammer I assumed the format is UML.

Comment: @shmosel It's a little out of context, but not a bad assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that it wants me to set up an array as a parameter to the
>   method but I don't know exactly how to set it up.

**Simply do something along the line of this:**

```
aBook[] tempBooks = new aBook[2]; // you can change the length if you wish
aBook book1 = new aBook();
aBook book2 = new aBook();
tempBooks[0] = book1;
tempBooks[1] = book2;
```

**The method implementation:**

```
public boolean addBook(aBook[] book){
   if(Some Condition){                // this is just an example but you know better than me of what your algorithm is.
       // perform some task
       return true;  // return true;
   }
   return false; // return false otherwise
}
```

**Call the method:**

```
addBook(tempBooks);
```

Of course without knowing how your `constructor` looks for the `aBook` type I can only suggest the example I have provided above.

**UPDATE**

I think what your method definition states is to pass a `book` into the method `addBook(aBook book)` and then add that `book` to an array of `aBook`, depending on whether the book is added or not you'll return the appropriate `return` value.

**Example:**

Assume this array is global within your class:

```
aBook[] tempBooks = new aBook[2]; // you can change the length if you wish
```

Create some variable to hold the current Index, so now your code becomes like this:

```
aBook[] tempBooks = new aBook[2]; // you can change the length if you wish
int index = 0;
```

Within your `addBook(aBook book)` method:

```
public boolean addBook(aBook book){
   if(book != null){                // this is just an example but you know better than me of what your algorithm is.
     if(index < tempBooks.length){
       tempBooks[index] = book;
       index++;
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false; // return false otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that format is written in [UML](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/).

Which may represent:

`public boolean addBook(Book aBook);`  or  `public boolean addBook(Book[] aBook);`

Answer (score -2):

As it is written:

```
public boolean addBook(aBook[] book)
```

You are creating a method that accepts an array of aBook objects as a parameter and must return a true or false boolean value.

One suggestion is to use proper naming convention. aBook should start with a capital letter, since it is a class. I.e. A_Book.

Comment: What is this answering?

Comment: P. Help's question.

Comment: "You are creating a method that accepts an array of aBook objects as a parameter and must return a true or false boolean value." That part is exactly what i am supposed to be doing. I have a attribute named MAX and i return true if there is a max number of items in the array and false if there isn't so would what i have be correct then?

Comment: Yes, you just need the internal logic in your method to evaluate the size of your array versus the MAX value. 
Ensure you use .length() on your array to get the size, if you go by index there will be a zero offset.